# Angular Webpack Adding Bootstrap ... [Error] File to import not found or unreadable: ../bootstrap/scss/_pager

Tags: file, angular, webpack, bootstrap-4

For my project I will be using Bootstrap.

I try to install `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5"`

Using this tutorial https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-4-and-Sass-(and-jQuery)

But it will not work for me :'(.

I'm seeing this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js
Module build failed:
undefined
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ../bootstrap/scss/_pager
Parent style sheet: stdin
      in D:\Projets\PROJECT\workspace\project-front\node_modules\bootstrap-loader\no-op.js (line 24, column 1)
 @ ./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/bootstrap-loader/lib/bootstrap.styles.loader.js!./~/bootstrap-loader/no-op.js 4:14-164
```

Do you have any ideas or a solution for me ;)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I resolved this issue by turning a few params to false in the `.bootstraprc`.

```
  pager: false
  labels: false

  utilities-background: false
  utilities-spacing: false
  utilities-responsive: false
```